# Better solution for holding appliances inside the aquarium?

Tags: aquarium, filters, maintenance, equipment

We've all seen these devices. They're the suction-cup clamps used to affix heaters, filter intakes, tubing, and other appliances inside the aquarium.

[image]

But the suction cups quickly deteriorate and no longer stick, the clamps loosen, and soon any torque on the appliances breaks things lose and leaves them hanging in the water. It makes the tank look like it always needs to be *"put back together."*

I have my tank set up pretty much the way I want it to stay. Is there a more robust solution to holding fixtures inside the tanks so they don't start deteriorating weeks after they are installed? Maybe something designed to be a bit more "semi-permanent." I'm thinking something hot-glued or somehow clamped or built into the framework of the tank itself.

Comment: In your  case it is probably too late since you have all the equipment but in my tank I don't have any suction cup. But it surely depend on the size of the tank. In my case the filter is a hand on the back and the heater keep himself in place with the top of the glass

Answer (score 3):

I used silicon sealant in my Oscars tank as he kept moving the heater and tank décor. As long as it's practical to lower the water level whilst you do it, it's a great permanent solution. Just be sure to buy aquarium safe sealant as domestic silicone contains algae and bacteria inhibitors, which are harmful to fish. Most fish shops sell it in small tubes but it's cheaper to go online and buy one of the tubes to use in a sealant gun.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the the suction cups with magnets. http://www.marinedepot.com/Zoo_Med_MagClip_Magnetic_Suction_Cups_Heater_Accessories-Zoo_Med-MZ4111-FIHTHA-vi.html

Comment: I've been using these for a long time, and they're not perfect but are substantially better than suction cups. Definitely worth the money in the long term. They work great for mounting single frags in a reef tank as well.